# Help with a minecraft slime farm

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was strolling around in a large labyrinth of abandoned mine tunnels on my Windows 10 Bedrock minecraft survival game and I found a slime chunk. I cleared the entire chunk out and lit it up below level 40, and slimes spawned for a bit, then stopped. I did some research, and found a lot of information about this topic, but most of it is a few years old and for Java Edition.

After the research I've done I'm pretty sure that the problem is that too many other mobs are spawning somewhere in the area and preventing the slimes from spawning. However, I'm uncertain is exactly how to go about fixing this, for a few reasons.

Most of the info I found suggested lighting up a 128 block radius around the slime chunk, but I'm know Bedrock spawning mechanics are a bit different than Java so this might not be the right number for what I need, plus there are (as previously mentioned) a LOT of tunnels in the area and I'd probably have to dig out the ENTIRE several chunk area to find them all and light them up, which is a lot of work to do if I'm not even sure if it will work yet or exactly how far out I need to go. In addition, Bedrock has that "simulation distance" slider, which I like to keep turned up pretty high so I can see long distances and keep nearby farms etc. operating at longer range, and I have this horrible feeling this might also affect where and what mobs are counted. Help?

Comment: You definitely do need to light up a large radius around your farm. The surface too, because night. You don’t need to dig them out, just torch existing tunnels. This is the painful problem with mob farms in general. Another option is to have your AFK spot high in the sky, so your spawn sphere only intersects the ground in a limited area including your farm and limited area around it.

Comment: I know I need to light an area around my farm. My question is HOW FAR? And how do you suggest I find all the caves and tunnels to light them without digging out the area? There are a LOT of them. It's a large abandoned mine that spawned in an area that already had a lot of caves.

Comment: See [the wiki page on Spawn](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Spawn#Bedrock_Edition)